# No route matches when trying to delete images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm using active_storage for handling images and when trying to delete an image attached to a job post i get a no route match error.

```
No route matches [GET] "/jobs/51/delete_image_attachment"
```

Delete action in edit form

```
<% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
  <%= image_tag image, size: "120x120" %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', delete_image_attachment_job_url(image.id),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Delete method in jobs controller

```
 def delete_image_attachment
    @image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    @image.purge
    redirect_back(fallback_location: job_path) 
  end
```

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: Do you have `delete_image_attachment` method in `routes.rb`?

Comment: @Mark using 5.2.3

Comment: @Vasilisa Yes the method is in the routes

Comment: @sokoine now I see, link works as GET, not as DELETE. From the docs: "Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET". Maybe it is the problem?

Comment: Or you did not import [rails-ujs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements). Are you getting a javascript confirm popup when you click the link?

Comment: @AbM that fixed it thanks! rails-ujs was missing in application.js

Answer (score 0):

Solved by AbM in the comments, //= require rails-ujs was missing in application.js